# Отказ в pull после смены пароля от учетки git

Tags: git, github, git-pull

После смены пароля от учетки на github на сервере при попытке запулить коммит выдает ошибку:

> ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

В каком то конфиге надо сменить пароль от учетки на сервере, но где, не могу понять. Доступ только по ssh.

Так я думал изначально, потому что когда я обратно сменил пароль на старый, pull так же не отрабатывает.

Поскольку репозиторий приватный, я удалил оттуда несколько человек и возможно один из них и был залогинен на сервере и получал данные с гита.

Comment: вам надо добавить (с нужными полномочиями) публичную часть ключа, секретная часть которого хранится в каталоге `~/.ssh` у пользователя, от имени которого выполняется команда `pull`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а как узнать какой пользователь вообще на сервере на данный момент? И как его сменить, если там пользователь, которого уже исключили из работы.

Comment: *а как узнать какой пользователь вообще на сервере на данный момент?* — тот, от имени которого вы «запуливаете коммит». вы не знаете его имя? оно хранится, например, в переменной окружения `$USER`

Comment: Перегенерировал ssh ключ в общем и все заработало.

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста, полноценный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

Answer (score 1):

Выглядит, как будто ssh ключ на GitHub не совпадает с ключем, используемым на вашем компьютере. Попробуйте выполнить

`ssh-keygen`

после чего скопируйте содержимое файла `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` в ключи вашего аккаунта GitHub

Пример того, как это сделать, можно посмотреть [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6RFFNCAd9w&t=4s)